# Can I create customize content assit for JAVA in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

How can I create customize content assit on eclipse ?

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> ( In Mac.. <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>).. I got content assit. For instance: I type "**sysout**" and then get content assit. That may show **System.out.println();**
So , I want to do is save key for ("forloop"). I type "**forloop**" and then when I get content assit (press Ctrl+space or Command + space ) that should generate as...

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i ++) {

}
```

This is an example for I want to do. Can I get it ? If so, how to figure it out ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can. Go to Window/Preferences.

Inside that dialog go to Java/Editor/Templates and there you can add your own code template.